# getting can't validate error (13) for mlab for heroku

Tags: mongodb, heroku, mongoid

I'm trying to connect to a mongoDB instance hosted by mlab from heroku but It just keeps responding with:

`validate!': not authorized for query on .lotto_results (13)'

Which doesn't make sense as the user account has dbOwner role which means it should be able to read and write.

I found somthing about how heroku's nature (how it restarts) can cause problems but It didn't seem to explain how to fix it ( I would like to give a link to this but I can't seem to find the web page, it was a google thread I think).

I'm using the mongoid gem, with sinatra and grape and sprockets for assets (if that helps).

Not sure what else to mention, if there's anything else just ask and I'll try to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I solved the problem by changing my config to:

```
development:
  clients:
    default:
      uri:  <%= ENV['MONGOLAB_URI'] %>
```

which used the pre-generated uri and it suddenly started working, well kind of, I'm still having issues but it's not an authentication issue at least.